# "list object has no attribute " error while passing parameter to a function

Tags: python-3.x, singly-linked-list

I am trying to solve a problem to add two numbers using link list. I have used the below code which is complied correctly. But if I want to test it by passing parameters I am getting an error " list object  has no attribute 'val'

```py
#Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
         def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next

class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode)--> ListNode:
        dummy = ListNode()
        cur = dummy

        carry = 0
        while l1 or l2 or carry:
            v1 = l1.val if l1 else 0
            v2 = l2.val if l2 else 0

            # new digit
            val = v1 + v2 + carry
            carry = val // 10
            val = val % 10
            cur.next = ListNode(val)

            # update ptrs
            cur = cur.next
            l1 = l1.next if l1 else None
            l2 = l2.next if l2 else None

        return dummy.next
a =Solution()

a.addTwoNumbers([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

---

edit

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list. 
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        dummy = ListNode()
        cur = dummy

        carry = 0
        while l1 or l2 or carry:
            v1 = l1.val if l1 else 0
            v2 = l2.val if l2 else 0

            # new digit
            val = v1 + v2 + carry
            carry = val // 10
            val = val % 10
            cur.next = ListNode(val)

            # update ptrs
            cur = cur.next
            l1 = l1.next if l1 else None
            l2 = l2.next if l2 else None

        return dummy.next

    def insert_at_end(self,val):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head=ListNode(val,None)
            return
        itr=self.head
        while itr.next:
            itr=itr.next
        itr.next=ListNode(val,None)

    def print(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Linked List is empty")
            return

        itr=self.head
        llstr=""

        while itr:
            llstr +=str(itr.val)
            itr=itr.next
        print(llstr)

ll=Solution()
ll.insert_at_end([1,2,3])
ll.insert_at_end([4,5,6])
ll.print()
```

Comment: You're passing the functions lists, not ListNodes. Maybe you should write a function that takes a list and produces a ListNode

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks a lot for your reply. I am very new to python. If possible can you please write me a snippet if possible?

Comment: I encourage you to try for yourself, from your code here you probably understand everything you need to do it. Maybe as a first step, write some code that takes a linked list and a value and adds that value to the end of the linked list

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks again.Now I have created two linked list with my inputs but stuck at the final step where I want to see the results. If you can have a look in the new edit where I have added two function to add a LL at the end and print too.